# *** ERROR *** The PHP configuration loaded file is: c:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.1.0/php.ini - should be: c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.53.1/bin/php.ini

Tags: php, apache, wampserver

I updated from PHP 7.4.26 to PHP 8.1.0

I am getting the following error on localhost home page although website is working on server:

> ERROR The PHP configuration loaded file is: c:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.1.0/php.ini - should be: c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.51/bin/php.ini or c:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.1.0/phpforapache.ini
> You must perform: Right-click icon Wampmanager -> Refresh

- This file is only for PHP in Command Line.

How can I load the correct php.ini or make the error disappear?

Thanks.

Update: Please click below

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUnSN.jpg)

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www"
    <IfModule fcgid_module>
    Define FCGIPHPVERSION "8.1.0"
    FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC ${PHPROOT}${FCGIPHPVERSION}
    <Files ~ "\.php$">
      Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews +ExecCGI
      AddHandler fcgid-script .php
      FcgidWrapper "${PHPROOT}${FCGIPHPVERSION}/php-cgi.exe" .php
    </Files>
  </IfModule>
    <Directory "c:/wamp64/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#
```

```
PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\bhavi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
```

httpd.conf contains:

```
PHPIniDir "${APACHE_DIR}/bin"
LoadModule php_module "${INSTALL_DIR}/bin/php/php8.1.0/php8apache2_4.dll"

LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
<IfModule fcgid_module>
  FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 300
  FcgidConnectTimeout 10
  FcgidProcessLifeTime 1800
  FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 0
  FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0
  FcgidFixPathinfo 0
  FcgidZombieScanInterval 20
  FcgidMaxRequestLen 536870912
  FcgidBusyTimeout 120
  FcgidIOTimeout 120
  FcgidTimeScore 3
  FcgidPassHeader Authorization
  Define PHPROOT ${INSTALL_DIR}/bin/php/php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of the error or edit your question using markup to distinguish between the error and your notes on the error?

Comment: Sorry, the error message shown above is between '''' and ''''.

Comment: I have now added screenshot, thanks.

Comment: Did you actually intend to install `Apache 2.4.52fcgi` the Fcgi version of WAMPServer. Its the first release that allows FCGI and it sounds like you are not actually familiar with what that may mean. If you did not specifically want to use FCGI, can I suggest you upgrade to `Apache 2.4.52` or maybe the latest `Apache 2.4.53`

Comment: I have upgraded to Apache 2.4.53.1 and PhpMyAdmin 5.2.0. You are correct: I am not too familiar with FCGI and probably don't need it as my site is unlikely to get heavy traffic. Despite the error, the websites seem to be working well. (The error persists after upgrading).

Comment: Did you do as suggested in the error message? ___You must perform: Right-click icon Wampmanager -> Refresh___

Comment: Unfortunately right click and refresh made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Search your apache server files for `PHPINIDir`. In XAMPP it is under `\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf`. My PHPINIDir directive looks like:

```
<IfModule php7_module>
    PHPINIDir "P:/xampp7.3/php"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: httpd.conf contents updated above.

Comment: This didnt work: PHPIniDir "c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.51/bin/php.ini"
LoadModule php_module "c:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.1.0/php8apache2_4.dll"

Comment: Right click Refresh of Wampserver produced:  PHPIniDir "${INSTALL_DIR}/bin/apache/apache2.4.51/bin/php.ini"
LoadModule php_module "${INSTALL_DIR}/bin/apache/apache2.4.51/bin/php.ini"  BUT STILL GET THE ERROR.  Perhaps windows registry needs updating.